# What is the difference between `go get ...` and `go get -u ...`?

Tags: go

In go mod, what is the difference between `go get ...` and `go get -u ...` commands?

Comment: https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Add_dependencies_to_current_module_and_install_them

Comment: Run `go help get` and it will tell you what every parameter does. Same for any other Go command.

Comment: thanks.. as a newbie I was not able to list the help because I typed "go get help"..

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You would use `-u` to update the dependencies to their latest available minor and patch versions. So if your module is using package `foo.com/bar`, running `go get -u foo.com/bar` will update not only `foo.com/bar` to the latest MINOR.PATCH, but also its dependencies.

Go modules follows [semver](https://semver.org/): MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH

Changes in MINOR and PATCH should never break users, so they are "safe" to automatically update. That said, the conservative approach (without `-u`) doesn't update them and is appropriate in some cases.

---

An interesting quote from the [modules wiki](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules):

> A common mistake is thinking go get -u foo solely gets the latest
> version of foo. In actuality, the -u in go get -u foo or go get -u
> foo@latest means to also get the latest versions for all of the direct
> and indirect dependencies of foo. A common starting point when
> upgrading foo is instead to do go get foo or go get foo@latest without
> a -u (and after things are working, consider go get -u=patch foo, go
> get -u=patch, go get -u foo, or go get -u).